# How to round all values in a matrix?

Tags: r, rounding

I use the following method to store all my correlations in a matrix:

```
corrs <- cor(dataset, use="pairwise.complete.obs")
```

But now I'd like to round the values to two digits after the comma. How can I do that? I just found a round function but don't know how to apply it to all values.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just as in your other question, use the function (`round`) you found :)

```
corrs <- round(cor(dataset, use="pairwise.complete.obs"), 2)
```

For example:

```
> round(cor(cars),2)
      speed dist
speed  1.00 0.81
dist   0.81 1.00
```

Comment: @Roflcoptr: you are very welcome! It takes some time to get used to the wonderful world of R, I also find interesting (but trivial for others) function every day :) And learning the lang definitely worths it! If you feel lost and have time, check the docs about R which would provide a quite structured knowledge (what I lack unfortunately): http://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html, and also check "R inferno" which is a great resource!