# How to round values in R list - round only numeric values?

Tags: r, rounding

My question seems to be as simple as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453109/how-to-round-all-values-in-a-matrix), but I don't understand what is wrong.

I have following data:

```
myData <- structure(list(structure(0.964671123392506, .Names = "W"), 0.022361343060769242, 
                         structure(0.964695704055953, .Names = "W"), 0.022162269470046909, 
                         structure(0.958418109351607, .Names = "W"), 0.045107813263059401, 
                         structure(0.874545371360235, .Names = "W"), 1.59340622525965e-06), .Dim = c(2L, 
                                                                                                     4L), .Dimnames = list(c("Measure", "c-value"), c("col1", 
                                                                                                                                                      "col2", "col3", "col4")))
```

which are list:

```
typeof(myData)
[1] "list"
```

I wish to round all element to selected number of digits. I can't simply apply round function, so I wrote following function:

```
roundMe <- function(x, numbers=3) 
  {
  if ( is.numeric(x) ) {x <- as.character(sprintf("%3.2f", round(x, digits=numbers)))}
  #there's problem:
  x
}
```

and tried to apply it

```
apply(myData,1:2,roundMe)
```

which gives:

```
        col1   col2   col3   col4  
Measure List,1 List,1 List,1 List,1
c-value List,1 List,1 List,1 List,1
```

when I change "x" in roundMe (last line of function) to as.character(x), it returns not rounded number.
What is wrong? Should I use another apply function? Should I convert list to for example data frame?

Comment: Is there a reason you are working with this particular structure?

Comment: Also, all you have are numeric values.  Not sure why you are checking for numeric when they're all numeric.  Also, you cannot use  `round()` on a character string.

Comment: I retrieved mentioned structure (I change column and row names) following this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21239826/using-shapiro-test-on-multiple-columns-in-a-data-frame

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a list. Don't use `apply`, that will coerce to a matrix, instead use `lapply` in conjunction with `[<-` to replace the contents of `myData` while keeping the original structure,

Now, I can't see any reason why you would be attempting to coerce to a character when you could just use `round` and retain a numeric field

```
myData[] <- lapply(myData,round,2)
myData
#         col1 col2 col3 col4
# Measure 0.96 0.96 0.96 0.87
# c-value 0.02 0.02 0.05 0
```

Comment: Why myData[] is needed instead myData (to preserve list type?)